# Accesing local defined variable in other functions - Swift

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit, skspritenode, local-variables

I am making a game kind of like Space Invaders. 
I have a function that creates invaders at a random `position.x`.

Inside my `addInvader()`, I have defined the attacker as a `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "someImage")`.

This have to be defined inside the function, since there are added a new `attacker` every second.

My problem is inside another function:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if attacker.position.y < CGFloat(size.height/5*2)
        attacker.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "someOtherImage")
    }
}
```

Since the `attacker` constant is local, the `update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)` function can`t access it.

How can I access the `attacker.position` inside the update-function?

Comment: The short answer is you can't. By definition a local variable is visible only inside the function that defines it.

Comment: Maybe you should store a reference to the `attacker` in a global variable or a structure/class variable. Then you can access it in your update function.

Comment: Another way to proceed is to give a name to `attacker` and retriev it by it's name.

Comment: If you plan to add multiple attackers, you may want to add them to a container node (an `SKNode`) and then loop over the `children` of that node. You will need to add the container to the scene and the attackers to the container. The container node should be defined above `didMoveToView` to have global scope within `GameScene`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a global array called `attackers`.
Then I simply added the each attacker to the array.

With an algorythm, I made sure the `update`function was keeping track of the right attacker.

Answer (score 0):

> ***There is no way you can access a variable that was defined privately in a method.***

## **But what you can do is this..**

#### In your `addInvader()` method, below this

```
var attacker = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "someImage")
```

#### You will want to add the following code

```
attacker.name = "attacker"
```

#### You can set the `attacker.name` to anything you want to that is a `String`.

**Setting this will allow us find the node in the SKScene and use it so**

**Now once we have that set we are ready to move on to the `update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)` method. Inside the `update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)` simply add this line of code before anything else**

```
let attacker =  self.childNodeWithName("attacker") as! SKSpriteNode
```

**What that does is it loops through all of the children in the `SKScene` and looks for one with a name called `attacker` or whatever you set. If the `attacker` node is not a child of the `SKScene` and is a child of another variable for example `attackerParent` then what you can do is this**

```
let attcker = attackerParent.childNodeWithName("attacker") as! SKSpriteNode
```

#### So now your update function will look something like this

```
let attacker = self.childNodeWithName("attacker") as! SKSpriteNode

if attacker.position.y < CGFloat(size.height/5*2) {

    attacker.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "someOtherImage")

}
```

***Also a quick tip, if you want to change a texture of an `SKSpriteNode` do it like so***

```
var texture = SKTexture(imageNamed : "someOtherImage")
attacker.texture = texture
```

Comment: This seems like really good and understandable code! Thanks a lot!
However, moving to the GameScene causes the app to crash. Error:
"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
The line with "let attacker = self.childNodeWithName("attacker") as! SKSpriteNode" turns green.

Comment: make sure the attacker.name is the exact same as what you put in as the parameter for the function and make sure it is a child of the scene